# How to compare data using plot bar

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two value_counts() data:

```
languages_1 = q1['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.split(';', expand = True).stack().value_counts()    
languages_2 = q2['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.split(';', expand = True).stack().value_counts()
```

I can easily display these two separate values:

```
languages_1.plot(kind = "bar")
languages_2.plot(kind = "bar")
```

But I want to display them in the same plot as in the image:

[image]

I tried in this way:

```
from collections import Counter

x = dict(languages_18)
y = dict(languages_19)

array_languages_18 = []
array_languages_19 = []

array_numbers_18 = []
array_numbers_19 = []

count = 25
for (k, v) in x.items():
    count = count-1
    array_languages_18.append(k)
    array_numbers_18.append(v)
    if count == 0:
        count = 25
        break

for (k, v) in y.items():
    count = count-1
    array_languages_19.append(k)
    array_numbers_19.append(v)
    if count == 0:
        break

df_comparison = pd.DataFrame({'2019': array_numbers_19,
                   '2018': array_numbers_18}, index=array_languages_19)

ax = df_comparison.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [40, 20]
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 40})
```

But are there better solutions to achieve it?

Any hints? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
languages_1 = q1['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.split(';', expand = True).stack().value_counts()    
languages_2 = q2['LanguageWorkedWith'].str.split(';', expand = True).stack().value_counts()    

df_comparison = pd.concat([languages_1.combine(languages_2,max).rename('languages_1').fillna(0), 
                           languages_2.combine(languages_1,max).rename('languages_2').fillna(0)], axis=1)

ax = df_comparison.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [40, 20]
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 40})
```